# Legacy SSH clients on internal networks

Tags: networking, ssh, encryption

I have a couple of legacy SSH clients on my internal network (think 2000's era Macintoshes and the like) that are wholly incompatible with newer ciphers and key algorithms used in modern SSH implementations.

Getting these clients to work required adding `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` to `KexAlgorithms`, and `arcfour` to `Ciphers`.

**I understand that both of these are terribly, hopelessly broken from an encryption standpoint**. Unfortunately, the host in question also has inbound access from the internet, and I really, *really* don't want to have these crap ciphers enabled if I can avoid it, but it was the fastest way to get my clients back online.

I've got a few questions about how to tighten this setup down:

- Does sshd have a way to specify that certain addresses can use certain ciphers?

  - Regarding [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/148160/sshd-specify-different-ciphers-based-on-incoming-host/) from 2011: did sshd learn how to use `KexAlgorithms` and `Ciphers` inside of a `Match` block in the last 5 years?
- Is there some way to put a bastion/jump server in front of the clients requiring weak encryption, and then forward that connection on to the host with stronger encryption?
- Am I missing some other obvious way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does sshd have a way to specify that certain addresses can use certain ciphers?

Yes. Simple examples are on the [Legacy page of OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html). In short:

```
Host legacy.example.org
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    Ciphers +arcfour
```

> Is there some way to put a bastion/jump server in front of the clients requiring weak encryption, and then forward that connection on to the host with stronger encryption?

Yes. You can set the legacy server to accept connections only from the jumpbox server for example using `/etc/hosts.allow` (`tcp_wrappers`). For example:

```
sshd: <IP/hostname of bastion>
```

The users will then configure `ProxyCommand` to jump over the `jumpbox`, such as

```
Host legacy.example.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy.example.com
```

Comment: SSH host options are client side, which is not useful for allowing an older client to connect to a newer server. The problem is that the server removed broken ciphers from the default accept list, while the client *only* has these ciphers. I'd like to enable them server side for only the clients that require them.

Comment: You can do quite the same thing in the `sshd_config` to allow legacy clients to connect.

Comment: Is this a reference to host-based authentication? Adding a `Host` keyword itself to `sshd_config` results in the error `Bad configuration option: Host` from `sshd -t` for me (OpenSSH 8.9)

Comment: @tajmorton indeed, not exactly the same thing, but the `KexAlgorithms`/`Ciphers` work there. If you need to limit it to some hosts only, use the `Match` keyword as suggested by the manual pages.